# sbt assembly not publishing fat jar

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I can `sbt assembly` myself a fat jar without an issue with the below build.sbt file. However when I try to publish this "fat jar", `sbt publish` dumps only 1kb .jar files in the s3 bucket.

<s>Unzipping the .jar file shows that it only contains a manifest file.</s>

How do I get the fat jar into my repo?

***update: striked text has been altered since initial question was posed. Removed the name override and it now publishes the build code but without the external libraries***

below, my build.sbt file

```
name := "util_myutil"

version := "1.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.0-cdh5.5.2" % "provided"

unmanagedJars in Compile += file(".lib/my.jar")
unmanagedJars in Compile += file(".lib/some_other.jar")


assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

<s>assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"</s>

```
ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Cloudera repos" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos",
  "Cloudera releases" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-release",
  "Era7 maven releases" at "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/releases.era7.com"
)

s3sse := true
s3region := com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Region.US_Standard
s3acl := com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList.Private
s3overwrite := true
publishMavenStyle := true

publishTo := {
  val suffix = if (isSnapshot.value) "snapshots" else "releases"
  Some(s3resolver.value(s"IT Insights Artifacts $suffix", s3("my-mvn-repo." + suffix)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly:

add this to your build.sbt:

```
artifact in (Compile, assembly) := {
  val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)
```